# What causes this problem, whereby the query used in phpmyAdmin and in a nodejs app, gets different results?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, node-mysql2

I have tried this query in phpmyAdmin

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM meal_participants_user 
INNER JOIN user ON meal_participants_user.userId = user.id 
ORDER BY meal_participants_user.mealId ASC;
```

And got in phpMyAdmin the answer 6,

But when I ran this in a nodeJs app,

I got this answer

```
|count(*)|
| 8      |
```

What causes this problem and how can I fix it?

note: all data are not real
Tables

User:

[image: User]

meal_participants_user

[image: meal_participants_user]

Comment: Based on your table data, which one is the correct result?

Comment: `ORDER BY` makes no sense in this query. There's only one row returned, there's nothing to order.

Comment: I don't see any way that you can get a result of `8` with the data you show. If `user.id` is the primary key, the result can't be more than the number of rows in `meal_participants_user`.